# copy all the properties of config to obj unless they already exist in obj

Tags: javascript

Write a function named copyIf that takes 2 parameters: obj and config. The function should copy all the properties of config to obj unless they already exist in obj.

Comment: My hourly rate is 75$. Do you want me to write a contract? More seriously, if you got stuck at a certain point while trying to solve this (and show where you got stuck) we might help. Otherwise, we won't write code for you.

Comment: if you wont need write the answer by free you are welcome otherwise thanks you

Comment: I was trying to explain how stack overflow works, so next time you don't waste your time asking question that no-one will answer. But, hey, do as you please.

Comment: never mind  , and this is my time not your

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var obj ={ name : 'x', age:50, color : 'clo'};var config ={ name:'suhaib',id:25}; copyif(obj,config); function copyif(obj, config) { for (var prop in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { if(!config.hasOwnProperty(prop)) config[prop] = obj[prop]; } } console.log(config); }

```js
var obj ={ name : 'x', age:50, color : 'clo'};var config ={ name:'suhaib',id:25}; copyif(obj,config); function copyif(obj, config) { for (var prop in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { if(!config.hasOwnProperty(prop)) config[prop] = obj[prop]; } } console.log(config); }
```